# recent developments in American options?

Tags: option-pricing, reference-request, american-options

I have read the paper written by Egloff (2005) using machine learning techniques to solve the optimal stopping problem.

Is there any development in pricing American options during 2005-2016? (based on Monte Carlo)

I appreciate it if you can offer me some clues!

Comment: Songping Zhu, Exact and Explicit Solution for the Valuation of American Put Option, Quantitative Finance, Vol. 6, No. 3, June 2006, 229-242 (However, this method has not found practical application so far). Too complicated and slow.

Comment: Have you checked out Least Squares Monte Carlo method(2001) proposed by Longstaff and Schwartz? It’s widely used in the industry. [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hjfurrer/teaching/LongstaffSchwartzAmericanOptionsLeastSquareMonteCarlo.pdf)